# Partial method is not called?

Tags: c#, partial-classes

The partial method in File2 is never called. How to call `Init()` in File2?

**File1**

```
public partial class frmMy001 : Form, ITab1View
{
    public frmMy001()
    {
        Init();
    }

    partial void Init();
}
```

**File2**

```
public partial class frmMy001 : Form, ITab2View
{
    partial void Init();

    partial void Init()
    {
        ...// Breakpoint never hit
    }
}
```

Comment: The current code fails to compile, with "A partial method may not have multiple defining declarations". Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @JonSkeet It actually compiles on my VS 2015. Removing the partial Signatures failed compilation though.

Comment: That suggests you've got them in different namespaces then. (That's the kind of thing a *complete* example would have highlighted.) As an other way of demonstrating that, try adding a public member in one part and then calling it from the other part - I suspect you'll find you can't.

Comment: @JonSkeet Correct. I didn't pay attention the name space is different.

Comment: Right. At this point, you should either update the question or delete it. If you just update it, I'm happy to add an answer... but to be honest, as soon as you post that the namespaces are different, it's likely to be pretty obvious anyway.

Comment: Yes, I will delete the question. -- Cannot delete it since it's already answered.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the declaration in **File**

```
public partial class frmMy001 : Form, ITab2View
{
    // partial void Init(); <-- remove this

    partial void Init()
    {
        ...// Breakpoint never hit
    }
}
```

Your partial methods must meet the following conditions:

> - Signatures in both parts of the partial type must match.
> - The method must return void.
> - No access modifiers are allowed. Partial methods are implicitly private.

Comment: Better to comment it out to highlight what you're talking about, than delete it entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Partial method signature should be declared only in ONE part of a partial class. Try remove 'partial void Init();' declaration from File2.